# Отправка команды с сайта на сервер ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, запрос, скрипт, веб-сайт

У меня есть локальный сервак, на нём apache с простым одностраничным сайтом. Нужно сделать так, что бы по кнопке отправлялась команда на сервак и выполнила её. А как это сделать, без понятия.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить всё это дело в контейнерах.
https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/438982/